# Clustering algorithm that doesn't require predefining the number of clusters required

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning

I have a set of user queries from a search engine that I want to cluster. The only clustering algorithm I have come across so far is the [K-means clustering algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering), which requires defining the number of clusters up front. But in this case, I do not know how many clusters exist in the data. Is there any clustering algorithm that performs clustering without predefining the number of clusters?

Answer (score 3):

DBSCAN?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN

> DBSCAN requires two parameters: distance (eps) and the minimum number
>   of points required to form a cluster (minPts).

Answer (score 3):

There are several techniques that allow you to cluster unsupervised data. K-means is probably the most famous one. But as you have already seen, most k-means algorithms require the number of clusters to be specified in advance.

Nevertheless, at least two kinds of algorithms might suit your needs:

1. [Connectivity based clustering (hierarchical clustering)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_clustering#Connectivity_based_clustering_.28hierarchical_clustering.29);
2. [Density-based clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_clustering#Density-based_clustering) (such as [DBSCAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) or [OPTICS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPTICS_algorithm)).

By the way, there is a similar question in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136470/unsupervised-clustering-with-unknown-number-of-clusters).

Have fun!